# How to identify a pandas column is a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to identify if a column in pandas is a list (in each row).

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 2, 3], 'Y': [[34],[37,45],[48,50,57]],'Z':['A','B','C']})

df
Out[160]: 
   X             Y  Z
0  1          [34]  A
1  2      [37, 45]  B
2  3  [48, 50, 57]  C

df.dtypes
Out[161]: 
X     int64
Y    object
Z    object
dtype: object
```

Since the dtype of strings is "object", I'm unable to distinguish between columns that are strings and lists (of integer or strings).

How do I identify that column "Y" is a list of int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dataset is big, you should take a sample before apply the **type** function, then you can check:

If the the most common type is **list**:

```
df\
.sample(100)\
.applymap(type)\
.mode(0)\
.astype(str) == "<class 'list'>"
```

If all values are **list**:

```
(df\
.sample(100)\
.applymap(type)\
.astype(str) == "<class 'list'>")\
.all(0)
```

If any values are **list**:

```
(df\
.sample(100)\
.applymap(type)\
.astype(str) == "<class 'list'>")\
.any(0)
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), compare and then add [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if all values are `True`s:

```
print (df.applymap(type))
               X               Y              Z
0  <class 'int'>  <class 'list'>  <class 'str'>
1  <class 'int'>  <class 'list'>  <class 'str'>
2  <class 'int'>  <class 'list'>  <class 'str'>

a = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
print (a)
X    False
Y     True
Z    False
dtype: bool
```

Or:

```
a = df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).all()
print (a)
X    False
Y     True
Z    False
dtype: bool
```

And if need list of columns:

```
L = a.index[a].tolist()
print (L)
['Y']
```

If want check [`dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) (but `strings`, `list`, `dict` are `object`s):

```
print (df.dtypes)
X     int64
Y    object
Z    object
dtype: object

a = df.dtypes == 'int64'
print (a)
X     True
Y    False
Z    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! A quick follow up - does it compute the type for every element or does it fetch something that is pre-computed? Asking this because I may have a huge dataframe.

Comment: If need check `strings`, `lists` what are objects need `applymap`. But if need check `int64` or `float` is possible use `df.select_dtypes(include=['int64']).columns`, check [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html).